# Don't clear text input and validate error massage when navigate back

Tags: flutter, dispose, flutter-getx, textformfield

i'm using getx for state management. After type text or display an error message of textFormField, then i navigate to another screen. When i navigate back to this screen, i want to clear text input and error message, because this screen was not dispose, its just deactivate, but i realize getx doesn't have deactivate method. So I don't know how to handle it. Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you use Getx State management use onClose() instead of dispose()

Answer (score 0):

```
 Navigator.of(context).pop(_textEditingController.text);
```

Simply Navigate with your input value .